# How can i select closest input value on href click

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

How can I select the closest input value when I click on a link? I tried like this but I get `undefined`:

```
$(".change").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var qty = $(this).closest('input').val();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    alert(qty);
});
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/zhtsk06u/)

Comment: Can you include the HTML in your question?

Comment: can you try this? https://jsfiddle.net/zhtsk06u/4/

Comment: yep it's working, can you add it as an answer so i can accept it? i didn't know that i can use parent parent :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried using jQuery [parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/):

```
$(".change").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var qty = $(this).parents().eq(1).find('input').val();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    alert (qty);
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66y9v4kh/)